# Warning messages - running Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this warning message after I run Rails server. 
 SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
        This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
        provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
        cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
        future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

I don't want this warning messages. Keys are added to secrets.yml.  I've added rack 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

its just a warning message and not going to **stop/hinder** your rails application.if you want it to disappear,do what it says or update `rails` to version `3.2.13`